# Gostaria de colocar duas ações para um mesmo formulário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<form method="post" id="formulario_contato" onsubmit="validaForm(); return false; " class="form" action="?go=enviar">
                    <table id="login_table">
                    <div id="all">
                    <div id="login-box">
                    <p class="nome">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do paciente" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="idade">
                    <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" class="form-control" placeholder="Idade do paciente" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="cpf">
                    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class="form-control" placeholder="CPF do paciente" />
                    </p>

                    <!-- Botao Enviar -->
                    <p>
                    <center><input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info" href="sala_medico.php"/></center>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </table>
                    </form>

                    </div>
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(@$_GET['go']=='enviar'){
}
```

Eu estou cadastrando pessoas que podem escolher responder um questionário ou não. Desta forma, eu preciso de dois botões "cadastrar" para este mesmo formulário, um para cada ação. Caso seja impossível fazer deste jeito, qualquer outra solução é bem-vinda.

Comment: Quando você fala 'duas ações' você se refere ao atributo `action` do formulário? Você queria dois botões `submit` sendo que se clicar em um envia para um `action` e se clicar no outro envia para o outro `action`?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo. Eu coloquei na pagina o script que você mandou e o formulário. Mas no if para eu chamar a action eu coloco o que ?

Comment: É do jeito que está, você só vai alterar no script os campos **endereçoAction1** e **endereçoAction2** para especificar os endereços dos `actions` que você deseja para cada ocasião, ou seja, o `action` para o caso de o botão clicado ser o 1 (dentro do `if`) e o `action` para o caso de botão clicado ser o 2 (dentro do `else`).

Comment: Eu digo deste if aqui:                                                                                                                   <?php
if(@$_GET['go']=='enviar'){
}                                                                                                                                       Como eu coloco para executar uma função php dependendo do botão que apertar. Eu não entendi como que eu executo o action usando php

Comment: Esse `if` do `php` você não precisará mais dele, precisará apenas do script mesmo, o script já se encarregará de detectar o botão clicado e direcionar os dados para o respectivo `action`.

Comment: Sim, mas eu queria utilizar php dentro dos actions e não javascript. Eu ja fiz as funções dos actions em php e é bastante coisa :/

Comment: Então deveria ter deixado explícito na pergunta que queria somente em PHP e retirado as tags javascript e jQuery, pois, do modo que você colocou, fica como se servisse tanto em PHP, como em javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você deseja for alterar o atributo `action` do `form` de acordo com o botão clicado, segue exemplo utilizando `jquery`:

```js
$("#btnenviar1, #btnenviar2").click(function(){
  //Recebe o id do botão clicado
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  //Verifica qual foi o botão clicado através do id do mesmo e seta o action correspondente
  if (id == 'btnenviar1'){
      $('#formulario_contato').attr('action', 'endereçoAction1');
  }
  else {
      $('#formulario_contato').attr('action', 'endereçoAction2');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="formulario_contato" class="form" action="">
    <table id="login_table">
    <div id="all">
    <div id="login-box">
    <p class="nome">
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do paciente" />
    </p>

    <p class="idade">
    <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" class="form-control" placeholder="Idade do paciente" />
    </p>

    <p class="cpf">
    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class="form-control" placeholder="CPF do paciente" />
    </p>

    <!-- Botao Enviar -->
    <p>
    <center><input type="submit" id="btnenviar1" value="Cadastrar1" class="btn btn-info" href="sala_medico.php"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnenviar2" value="Cadastrar2" class="btn btn-info" href="sala_medico.php"/></center>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </table>
</form>
```